# Cannot initialise variable with an rvalue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, initialization, admob

I'm trying to integrate [Google's Consent SDK](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-ios) into an Xcode project, using the following code to show the Consent Form generated from the SDK:

```
//show consent form
[form presentFromViewController:_vc
    dismissCompletion:^(NSError *_Nullable error, BOOL userPrefersAdFree) {
    if (error) {
        // Handle error.
    } else if (userPrefersAdFree) {
        // The user prefers to use a paid version of the app.
    } else {
        // Check the user's consent choice.
        PACConsentStatus *status = PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus;
        // ERROR FOR ABOVE LINE
    }
}];
```

`_vc` is an how I access a viewController:

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
_vc = app.window.rootViewController;
```

For some reason, I seem to get the following error when trying to store the `consentStatus`:

`Cannot initialize a variable of type 'PACConsentStatus *' with an rvalue of type 'PACConsentStatus'`

Besides the way the viewController is presented, I follow [Admob's Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent) accurately.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining that you're assigning something of type `PACConsentStatus` to a variable of type `PACConsentStatus*` (a pointer to a `PACConsentStatus`). `PAConsentStatus` is an enum, not an object. Remove the star:

```
PACConsentStatus status = PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus;
```

Comment: If I remove the pointer, it becomes an unused variable and the form doesn't load.

Comment: Just assigning a value to a variable doesn't do anything by itself. I don't know what you mean by "the form doesn't load." I also don't know what `_vc_consent` is. That's a somewhat odd thing to pass to `presentFromViewController` (usually you pass `self` as show in the example you linked). I also don't know what `form` is or if it is non-nil. I would make sure you're following the linked example exactly (as noted, you have made changes).

Comment: Sorry. The form is the Consent Dialog form generated from the Consent SDK. I'm using a separate class, using a pointer to the viewController. Other than that, I haven't changed anything. From what I understand, this is supposed to store the consentStatus, not just save it as a variable. I will update my question.

Comment: Any updates on that issue?  I am getting the same error.

Comment: I was able to remove the "*" and the form loaded succesfully, not sure if theres any impact of not having the '*' but its not working with it so have to remove it